Getting an error when trying to use Preloader component in react framework7 with dark theme
I am using react framework7, and when I tried to use Preloader component in dark theme I got this runtime error:
Failed to execute ‘appendChild’ on ‘Node’: parameter 1 is not of type ‘Node’. TypeError: Failed to execute ‘appendChild’ on ‘Node’: parameter 1 is not of type ‘Node’.
It works fine with light theme(for both md and ios).
I tried the same thing using vite, but the error persists. I also tried wrapping my preloader in a div but nothing works. I double checked how I initialized the project and everything seems correct.
My component (where the error occurs):
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {
    Page,
     Preloader
} from "framework7-react";

const Splash = () => {
    return (
        <Page>
            <Preloader/>
        </Page>
    );
};

export default Splash;

App.js component:
import './App.css';
import { App, f7ready, View } from "framework7-react";
import Splash from "./Screens/Splash";

function MyApp() {
    f7ready(() => {
    });
    const f7params = {
        name: 'My App',
        routes: [
            {
                path: '/splash',
                component: Splash,
            },
        ],
    };
  return (
      <App theme="ios dark" name="My App" {...f7params}>
          <View main url="/splash" />
      </App>
  );
}

export default MyApp;

index.js:
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import App from './App';
import Framework7 from 'framework7/lite-bundle';
import  Framework7React  from 'framework7-react';
import 'framework7/css/bundle';


Framework7.use(Framework7React);

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <App />
   );

